# Видео записывает как зеркальное отражение

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Использую библиотеку для записи и просмотра видео [bullseye](https://github.com/aynurkacak/bullseye). Так вот изображение при записи нормальное то есть без зеркального отражения. Но вот при просмотре он уже зеркальный.

Кусок кода, где запись идет

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (!isRecording) {
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        isRecording = true;
                        progressTimer = new ProgressTimer(timerProgress * 100, 100);
                        progressTimer.start();
                        isVideoRecorded = true;
                    } else {
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (isRecording) {
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                    mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder
                    isRecording = false;
                    progressTimer.cancel();
                }

                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Попробовал

`mMediaRecorder.setorientationHint(0)`;

`mMediaRecorder.setorientationHint(270)`

Крешится! Как это решить?

Comment: на самом деле видео не **показывает**, а **записывается**, как зеркальное отображение.

Comment: Так в `MediaRecorder` дело. А почему тогда `if (isFrontCam) {
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
        }
        else
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);` не решает?

Comment: я не знаю, просто исправляю вашу формулировку вопроса после того, как прочитал его. Правильно будет в заголовке написать, что видео **записывается** не правильно, потому, что сейчас все выглядит так, что у вас проблемы не с записью, а с воспроизведением видео.

Comment: Аа хорошо, поправлю...